# jquery not working with infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and web developing but I'll do my best to give you the best damn question that you can ever have.

I'm using jQuery plug in to perform infinite scroll in a web-page that will only display images. This plugin is from [Infinite Scrolling though images](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/NxZKPR/). I have basically `copy/paste`but it's not working for some reason (I'm sorry I can't give you more details but I'm not too deep into web-developing).

I'm testing this demo in a virtual machine from [osboxes.org](http://www.osboxes.org). A linux machine (Ubuntu). I'm using right now firefox altought I tried using `Opera` or `Google Chrome` to see if it was some problem with the browser but it's not.

I have tried the following questions with no results:
[Infinite scrolling jquery not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053220/infinite-scrolling-jquery-not-working)

[jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

[Masonry callback in jQuery infinite scroll isn't working in Wordpress - and neither are infinite scroll plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457871/masonry-callback-in-jquery-infinite-scroll-isnt-working-in-wordpress-and-neit)

Here is the jQuery part:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).endlessScroll({
            inflowPixels: 300,
            callback: function() {
          var $img = $('#images li:nth-last-child(5)').clone();
          $('#images').append($img);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Body:

```
<h1>Infinite Scrolling, Demo 3</h1>

            <ul id="images">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
                        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
                        <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                .... some more images (30 more) .....
```

Unfortunally I can't seem to make the page go `infinite scroll`.

I have tried this simple example from `w3shool` and it works like a charm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#test").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="test">This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your Jquery script tag before the script for the plugin in your HTML page?  A fiddle or codepen would help us solve this.

Comment: @TimothyKanski Thank you for your time. Here's the `fiddle` that you asked for: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrsnadb0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the main function `endlessScroll` in your fiddle

So I updated your fiddle and added the respective function to it. You can find the new fiddle under this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xrsnadb0/1/)

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.endlessScroll = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      bottomPixels: 50,
      fireOnce: true,
      fireDelay: 150,
      loader: "<br />Loading...<br />",
      data: "",
      insertAfter: "div:last",
      resetCounter: function() {
        return false;
      },
      callback: function() {
        return true;
      },
      ceaseFire: function() {
        return false;
      }
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var firing = true;
    var fired = false;
    var fireSequence = 0;

    if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
      firing = false;
    }

    if (firing === true) {
      $(this).scroll(function() {
        if (options.ceaseFire.apply(this) === true) {
          firing = false;
          return; // Scroll will still get called, but nothing will happen
        }

        if (this == document || this == window) {
          var is_scrollable = $(document).height() - $(window).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels;
        } else {
          // calculates the actual height of the scrolling container
          var inner_wrap = $(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap", this);
          if (inner_wrap.length == 0) {
            inner_wrap = $(this).wrapInner("<div class=\"endless_scroll_inner_wrap\" />").find(".endless_scroll_inner_wrap");
          }
          var is_scrollable = inner_wrap.length > 0 &&
            (inner_wrap.height() - $(this).height() <= $(this).scrollTop() + options.bottomPixels);
        }

        if (is_scrollable && (options.fireOnce == false || (options.fireOnce == true && fired != true))) {
          if (options.resetCounter.apply(this) === true) fireSequence = 0;

          fired = true;
          fireSequence++;

          $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_loader\">" + options.loader + "</div>");

          data = typeof options.data == 'function' ? options.data.apply(this, [fireSequence]) : options.data;

          if (data !== false) {
            $(options.insertAfter).after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_data\">" + data + "</div>");
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").hide().fadeIn();
            $("div#endless_scroll_data").removeAttr("id");

            options.callback.apply(this, [fireSequence]);

            if (options.fireDelay !== false || options.fireDelay !== 0) {
              $("body").after("<div id=\"endless_scroll_marker\"></div>");
              // slight delay for preventing event firing twice
              $("div#endless_scroll_marker").fadeTo(options.fireDelay, 1, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                fired = false;
              });
            } else {
              fired = false;
            }
          }

          $("div#endless_scroll_loader").remove();
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);

$(document).endlessScroll({
  inflowPixels: 300,
  callback: function() {
    var $img = $('#images li:nth-last-child(5)').clone();
    $('#images').append($img);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 640px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Infinite Scrolling, Demo 3</h1>

<ul id="images">
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-sun-trees-path-21008/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/21008/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/cold-snow-landscape-nature-1127/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/1127/cold-snow-landscape-nature.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/coastline-aerial-view-sea-9148/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/9148/pexels-photo.jpeg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-sun-trees-path-21008/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/21008/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/cold-snow-landscape-nature-1127/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/1127/cold-snow-landscape-nature.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/coastline-aerial-view-sea-9148/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/9148/pexels-photo.jpeg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/7919/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-nature-sunset-trees-479/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/479/landscape-nature-sunset-trees.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/landscape-sun-trees-path-21008/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/21008/pexels-photo.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/cold-snow-landscape-nature-1127/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/1127/cold-snow-landscape-nature.jpg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.pexels.com/photo/coastline-aerial-view-sea-9148/">
      <img src="https://pexels.imgix.net/photos/9148/pexels-photo.jpeg?fit=crop&w=640&h=480" alt="" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I'm doing it correctly: You place the `function` inside a `<script>` tag right? Because if that's the case it's still not working.

Comment: OK, so please let me know if the fiddle that I have provided in my post working or not?